# Align Label and Image in a div center vertical and center horizontal

Tags: php, html, css

Aligning image at start and

I am using following code

```
<div id="ringName" style="background-color: #701344;height: 50px; border-radius: 4px;  width: 800px; ">
         <img style="margin-top:5; margin-left:20;" src="images/about_us_logo.png" alt="" width="40" height="40" /> 

     <div  style="font-size: 24px; color: #FFF; text-align: center; line-height: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 4px;  width: 760px; " ><?php echo $store['name'] ?></div>   
    </div>
```

What i want to do is, make a Voilet bar of `width 800px , height 50px`.

The `<img>` tag will show logo at like margin left 5 and margin top 5. Means at start in `center vertical` at start of The bar.

However I want to show the `store name` in the middle of the MAIN DIV, `CEnter horizontal, center vertical`.

In above code, the Text is not showing, and the margins to the logo are not working either.

What are the fixes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the debugged code: http://jsfiddle.net/u7G2M/.

HTML:

```
<div id="ringName">
    <img style="" src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="" /> 
    <div>Store Name</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #ringName {
    background-color: #701344;
    height: 50px; 
    border-radius: 4px;  
    width: 800px;
}

#ringName > img {
    margin-top:5px; 
    margin-left:20px; 
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#ringName > div {
    display: inline-block;
    font: 24px/50px Sans-Serif;
    color: #fff; 
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why but this is not working on chrome, any ideas?

Comment: It's working fine in my Chrome, Safari, Opera, and Firefox.  I even tested it in IE8 and with the exception of border-radius, everything is working well.  The original fiddle was written using Chrome as the environment.  Be specific.  What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
.className{

    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this answers the question?